# Python Tkinter Timer

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a clock in Tkinter and I am trying to create a timer however, whenever I try to start it the label just remains at the number chosen.

For the clock, I have an update variable that is always refreshing so I am trying to incorporate the timer into that. This is the update code:

```
def Update():
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    if TimerOn == True:
        root.after(1000, Update)
        root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
    else:
        root.after(1000, Update)
```

The "TimerOn" Variable is set true here:

```
def Start():
    Timer.config(font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
    Timer.place(x = "160", y = "250")
    TimerOn = True
```

Comment: In the absence of a `global` declaration, `TimerOn = True` is just creating a local variable that has no effect anywhere else in your program.

Comment: @jasonharper do I just have to add a `global TimerOn` when I'm defining the "Start" variable?

Comment: Also note `Timer` vs `Time`.